# Convolution is continuous map

Tags: analysis, continuity, lp-spaces, convolution

I can prove this when $f$ is assumed as continuous function but without assuming continuity i got confused.

Suppose $ p \in (1, \infty) $ and $q$ is its conjugate exponent. Prove that if $f\in L^p(\Bbb R)$ and $ g \in L^q(\Bbb R)$ then $f*g$ is uniformly continuous and $f*g(x) \to 0 $ as $x \to \infty$ and $x \to -\infty$,   where "$*$" denotes convolution.

Comment: Note that $C_c(\mathbb{R})$ is dense in $L^p$.

Comment: o yes yes thank you....

Comment: I am still confused, can anyone help me? I would appreciate..

Comment: Try approximating $f$ and/or $g$ with functions in $C_c(\mathbb{R})$. You've shown that the results hold true when $f$ is continuous and when you approximate $f$ by continuous functions, the result will hold at each approximation and so it will hold for $f$.